# Is there an API to reference places to the iOS maps app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, apple-maps

I am doing some online visibility for a modest stream of small and medium sized businesses (about 10-15 per week).

One of the things I have begun doing recently is making sure they appear on google maps. I submitt them to google maps places API, which then proceeds to make them appear on their maps after some verifications.

I'd like to be able to reference them *also* on the **iOS official maps**, but I don't know how to do it.

EDIT: I am referring [to this app](https://www.apple.com/ios/maps/).

I can't seem to find an API, and I think I won't be able to reference the stream of businesses  through the in-app process.

Also, maybe Apple assembles the maps data from other sources. If you know where from please post.

Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you actually try to google "Google Places API"?

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Make sure you reference their TOU as well:

https://developers.google.com/places/policies#terms_of_use

Comment: I have done extensive Googling prior to posting this question. I wish you had read that my question is intended for the iOS official maps app. I am looking for the Apple Maps Places API, not the Google Places API;  The data that is used by the maps application that Apple, not Google, makes available. As far as I know, this app does not use Google's data.

Comment: I did read your question, and it was unclear what you wanted up until you edited your post numerous times. All you said was "reference on Apple maps" and the "Places" API, which, to me, sounded like you want to use the Google Places API to display results on Apple maps, which is easy to do, but apparently not what you wanted.

Comment: It is now 2021 and I'm also wondering this. It's easy to use the Google Places API results on an Apple Maps, but unfortunately against the Google TOS (must be a google map).